# Convert DataFrame column type in datetime

Tags: python, pandas

How can I convert  a DataFrame column of strings (in d.days, d.seconds, d.microseconds format in positive timedelta) to datetime. ?

Thanks in Advance.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer by [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31407463/numpy-and-pandas-timedelta-error/31407805) was particularly useful I think.

```
def combine64(years, months=1, days=1, weeks=None, hours=None, minutes=None,
              seconds=None, milliseconds=None, microseconds=None, nanoseconds=None):
    """
    * Function: combine64 
    * Usage: df['combined']= combine64(df['Year'], df['Month'], df['Day']) . . .
    * -------------------------------
    * This function returns Datetime in the format YYYY-MM-DD:HH:mm:ss:ms:µs:ns
    """
    years = np.asarray(years) - 1970
    months = np.asarray(months) - 1
    days = np.asarray(days) - 1
    types = ('<M8[Y]', '<m8[M]', '<m8[D]', '<m8[W]', '<m8[h]',
             '<m8[m]', '<m8[s]', '<m8[ms]', '<m8[us]', '<m8[ns]')
    vals = (years, months, days, weeks, hours, minutes, seconds,
            milliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds)
    return sum(np.asarray(v, dtype=t) for t, v in zip(types, vals)
               if v is not None)
```

Comment: Thanks @SerialDec i Am clear up my confusion.

Comment: yeah absolutely